# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSHTTPURLResponse *' from 'NSURLResponse *'

Tags: ios, warnings, sharekit, incompatibility

I get the warning Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSHTTPURLResponse *' from 'NSURLResponse *' in the code below. This method is part of Sharekit.

The line with the warning is the bolded/italicized one:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
    if (response)
        [response release];
    ***response = [aResponse retain];***
    [responseData setLength:0];
}
```

Someone please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the compiler, `aResponse`, and the result of `[aResponse retain]`, is an NSURLResponse. However I'm guessing `response` is an NSHTTPURLResponse. Since NSURLResponse is a superclass of NSHTTPURLResponse, you can't just assign directly — but you can use a cast to remove the warning:

```
response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)[aResponse retain];
```